# package.json grunt dependences modules don't show up when i do a npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have created a package.json file with grunt dependencies I do my npm install but the grunt modules do not show up in my website hierarchy all I get is a bunch of warn in the terminal about different plugins that I didn't want. Also I am defiantly pointing to the right folder but it says they folder don't exist

```js
MacBook-Pro:Taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$ cd ~/Desktop/taylerramsay 
MacBook-Pro:taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$ npm install 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Tayler_Ramsay/package.json' 
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No description
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No repository field. 
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No README data 
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No license field. 
MacBook-Pro:taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$
```

Comment: have you tried npm install grunt --save

Comment: yes I went onto grunts page and tried it all I think somehow its seeing the wrong directory .im at work i have my laptop when i fire it up I will paste what I get thank you for responding.

Comment: could you add source code and terminal output,  please?

Comment: Sorry I am new I do not know how to format the code so it isn't all jumbled-------                           MacBook-Pro:Taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$ cd ~/Desktop/taylerramsay
MacBook-Pro:taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$ npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Tayler_Ramsay/package.json'
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No description
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No repository field.
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No README data
npm WARN Tayler_Ramsay No license field.
MacBook-Pro:taylerramsay Tayler_Ramsay$

Comment: add your package.json file please.

Answer (score 0):

**npm** tells you that there is no `package.json` file in your directory then it can install anything.

I recommend you to follow these step :
1. run `npm init` to create a valid `package.json` file with needed information
2. Install and save your npm modules in your `package.json` file with `--save` argument. (**E.g** : `npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin --save`)